# Send message every year to a list Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I'm trying to accomplish something in Sharepoint 2010, I currently have a list containing information and each items are related to a person (with the email adress in a column).  What I want to do is to send them a message at least each year to ask them to review the information and update it, if needed.  So a workflow would be needed.

I'm quite new to sharepoint, i've tried looking but didn't seem to find exactly what i'm looking for.  I think I could try something with the "Pause until" and the two workflows that will loop endlessly, but i'm really not sure.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of options, though none easily built without code (unless you have a 3rd party product). I would certainly recommend against the "Pause until..." approach inside a SharePoint Designer Workflow; it's both unreliable and unnecessarily taxing.

You could build & deploy a workflow via Visual Studio that would be able to include such timer-based logic. Another option would be to create a SharePoint Designer Workflow that is configured to start manually; you could create a SharePoint Timer Job that runs once a year to manually start the WF on every item in the List - or even write a small Powershell script that does so and even have an SP admin run it once a year (admittedly less elegant, I know).

In general, a SharePoint Designer Workflow will not allow you to build a WF that runs automatically once a year, so you'll either need to move to a layer in the stack that will or use a workflow to define what you want to happen but use other server-side mechanisms for kicking off the workflow on your schedule.